# error: QNetworkReply: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

Something is missing from the pro file it seems:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
HEADERS += hello.h
SOURCES += hello.cpp
QT += webkit
```

Or there is some other problem?

```
$qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.7.0 in /opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line was missing: `QT += network` in the .pro file.